# Product of N numbers, incorrect answer, possible overflow?

Tags: java, algorithm, overflow

I am trying to solve the problem "product of first n numbers"

```
   long ans=1;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        ans = ans*i;
    }
    return ans % (1000000007) ;
```

I am incorrect result for large n, I suspect possible overflow. How do I go about solving it?

Comment: Use biginteger instead of long

Comment: `ans = ans*i;` can be very huge and cause *integer overflow*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko how do we resolve that problem?

Comment: `return Enumerable.Range(1, n).Aggregate(1L, (s, a) => s * a % 1_000_000_007);`

Comment: @Max I believe my answer resolved some of your questions.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to write `answer % 1000000007`, you can (and I guess you should) use `%` operator every time in `for` loop.

```
long ans = 1;
long p = 1000000007;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ans = (ans * i) % p;
}

return ans;
```

If this is not enough, you can try this:

```
long ans = 1;
long p = 1000000007;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ans = ((ans % p) * (i % p)) % p;
}

return ans;
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind "If you have to write answer % 1000000007, you can (and I guess you should) use % operator every time in for loop.", what is the proof of correctness of this?

Comment: @Max you can check it here: https://brestprog.by/topics/modulo/
P.S. sorry for russian, i hope you can use Google Translator :)

Comment: Technically, the last `ans % p;` is redundant: `return ans;` is enough

Comment: What you are looking for is "modulus is closed under multiplication" (which is a fancy way of saying that  ((a mod n) * (b mod n)) mod n = (a*b) mod n.   Any book on basic number theory would have a proof, but also here: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-multiplication

Answer (score 0):

First, here is the `BigInteger` solution.

```
int p = 1_000_000_007;

BigInteger fact = BigInteger.TWO;
int N = 50;
for (int i = 3 ;i < N; i++) {
     fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
}
System.out.println(fact.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(p)));
```

prints

```
726372166
```

To solve this without using `BigInteger`, one can use the relationship that says that

```
 (a mod n) * (b mod n) = ab mod n.
```

Check out the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488529/prove-that-ab-bmod-n-a-bmod-n-b-bmod-n)

Since the above can be applied to a larger range of integers, one can do the following:

```
long mod = 2;
int N = 50;
for (int i = 3; i < N; i++) {
    mod = (mod * i) % p;
}
System.out.println(mod);
```

prints

```
726372166
```

Note:  `1_000_000_007` is a prime number and thus guarantees no product above will ever have that value as a factor.  If `N >= p` then all subsequent results will be `0`, even if the product is first computed using `BigInteger`, because the remainder will be zero when the product is divided by `p`